# Crystal Reports 2013: Formula repeating same error

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2013

First time trying to program with Crystal Reports. I am trying to write a simple enough one. There are different fields grouped together, and I am planning to run the formula on each group. In the below image is an example of a group.

[image: reportImage]

The highlighted `20.00` in the upper right corner of the image is the `shipctns`. My formula is

```
Local NumberVar RTotal := 0;
Local NumberVar diff := 0;
While RTotal <  {@shipctns} DO
(
 If ({@pickctns} <  {@shipctns}) AND (RTotal + {@pickctns} < {@shipctns}) THEN
    "Pick";
    RTotal := RTotal + {@pickctns};
 Else If  {@pickctns} <  {@shipctns}  THEN
    "Pick " & ({@shipctns} - RTotal);

 Else
    "Don't Pick"
);
```

The formula is still a work in progress. It's just to go through the `Pick Ctns` in each group, and say to pick this amount to make up the `shipctns` amount. Only select part of the last `Pick Ctns` if it is too large and then stop.

My problem is that I can't really test out the formula because I am getting an error on the `Else If` saying "The ) is Missing". I don't really know Crystal Reports so what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you need curly bracket with all fields

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm getting strange error now. I replaced all except the declaration of RTotal with {RTotal} and now I'm getting "This field is not recognised"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to surround multiple statements within a `then` or `else` block with parentheses.

From the Crystal Reports documentation:

> The correct Crystal syntax for If statements is `if <condition> then
>   <then> else <else>`, where `<condition>`, `<then>`, and `<else>` are all
>   single expressions. If you have multiple expressions after the `<then>`
>   or `<else>`, convert them into single expressions by surrounding them in
>   parentheses.

Your formula should look like this

```
...
If ({@pickctns} <  {@shipctns}) AND (RTotal + {@pickctns} < {@shipctns}) THEN
(
    "Pick";
    RTotal := RTotal + {@pickctns};
)
Else If  {@pickctns} <  {@shipctns}  THEN
    "Pick " & ({@shipctns} - RTotal);
Else
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I don't know if it really helped unfortunately. The error is now highlighting the "If" in the "Else If" saying expecting a number here

Comment: Swap `"Pick";` and `RTotal := RTotal + {@pickctns};`. AFAIK the last statement in a block implicitly determines the returntype of a formula. `RTotal := RTotal + {@pickctns};` causes your formula to return a number - but you are returning a text in your else if block.

Comment: Oh okay thank you! I didn't realize that was the problem. It is hard to search for things about crystal reports issues and not really knowing what the problem is.